# Preventing access to jar resources

Tags: java

I'd like to make the contents of my jar inaccessible to browsing (i.e. via WinRAR). 
Is there any other way except encryption to do so? 
If not, how would I encrypt the contents (about 1GB of data in .png and .mp3 files mostly) in a way so they are (somewhat) fast to decrypt (no need for safety from hackers, but I would like to use something more complicated than a Caesar cypher..).

Comment: JarCryp may help, it performs encryption/decryption tranparently: http://www.componio.com/products/jinstaller/jarcryp/index.html

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way other than encryption. Even encryption will not protect you from screenshotting, people taking a video on their cellphones, etc.

Comment: Screenshots are okay.. I'm just making this program for me and my friend, and I've rigged it so it won't activate until a certain date (and until then I've left it on their desktop), but I don't want them to browse the archive and figure out what's happening..